# Registering implementations of base class with Autofac to pass in via IEnumerable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a base class, and a series of other classes inheriting from this:
*(Please excuse the over-used animal analogy)*

> public abstract class Animal { }
>
> public class Dog : Animal { }
>
> public class Cat : Animal { }

I then have a class that has a dependancy on an `IEnumerable<Animal>`

```
public class AnimalFeeder
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Animal> _animals;

    public AnimalFeeder(IEnumerable<Animal> animals )
    {
        _animals = animals;
    }
}
```

If I manually do something like this:

```
var animals =
    typeof(Animal).Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal)))
        .ToList();
```

Then I can see that this returns `Dog` and `Cat`

However, when I try to wire up my Autofac like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Animal).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal)));

builder.RegisterType<AnimalFeeder>();
```

When `AnimalFeeder` is instantiated, there are no `Animal` passed in to the constructor.

Have I missed something?

Comment: You are probably missing the `As<Animal>()` in your registartion: `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Animal).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal))).As<Animal>();`

Comment: Might want to convert that comment to an answer! ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing the `As<Animal>()` call in your registration.

Without it Autofac will register your types with the default `AsSelf()` setting so you won't get your classes if you ask for base type with `IEnumerable<Animal>` only if you use the sub-types like Dog and Cat.

So change your registration to:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Animal).Assembly)
     .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Animal)))
     .As<Animal>();
```

Comment: I know this question is old but what if you want to register a named subclass of the abstract class?

Comment: Named registrations can be also resolved with `IEnumarable<T>` when they are registered with the type **and** the name. So `builder.RegisterType<Dog>().As<Animal>().Named<Animal>("Dog"); builder.RegisterType<Cat>().As<Animal>().Named<Animal>("Cat");` in this case `IEnumerable<Animal>` will return both, but you can also resolve the individual ones with: `container.ResolveNamed<Animal>("Dog");`. You can even combine it with the assembly scanning: `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(...).As<Animal>();` and then register your named ones additionally: `builder.RegisterType<Dog>().Named<Animal>("Dog");`

Comment: @nemesv: I was able to [get mine working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75845890) using your great tip here in the comments. Would you make this an answer over there so I can accept it? My final syntax: `oBuilder.RegisterType(Of CleanCommand).As(Of IBaseCommand).Named(Of BaseCommand)(NameOf(CleanCommand)).WithParameters(oParameters)` and `oCleanCommand = oScope.ResolveNamed(Of BaseCommand)(NameOf(CleanCommand))`, `oDownloader = oScope.Resolve(Of IDownloader)`.

Comment: @nemesv: p.s. I don't mind if the answer is in C#. In fact I prefer it, if that's easier for you.