# Autofac: how to register/resolve a type whose constructor takes an abstract type as its parameter?

Tags: inheritance, dependency-injection, abstract-class, autofac

I have two concrete classes that inherit from an abstract class:

```
Public Class UpdateCommand
  Inherits BaseCommand
  Implements IUpdateCommand

  Public Sub New(Root As DirectoryInfo)
    MyBase.New(Root)
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class CleanCommand
  Inherits BaseCommand
  Implements ICleanCommand

  Public Sub New(Root As DirectoryInfo)
    MyBase.New(Root)
  End Sub
End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseCommand
  Implements IBaseCommand

  Public Sub New(Root As DirectoryInfo)
    Me.Root = Root
  End Sub

  Protected ReadOnly Property Root As DirectoryInfo Implements IBaseCommand.Root
End Class
```

...and then I have this class next to them:

```
Public Class Downloader
  Implements IDownloader

  Public Sub New(Command As IBaseCommand)
    Me.Root = Command.Root
  End Sub

  Private ReadOnly Root As DirectoryInfo Implements IDownloader.Root
End Class
```

The interfaces are constructed similarly:

```
Public Interface IUpdateCommand
  Inherits IBaseCommand
End Interface

Public Interface ICleanCommand
  Inherits IBaseCommand
End Interface

Public Interface IBaseCommand
  ReadOnly Property Root As DirectoryInfo
End Interface

Public Interface IDownloader
  ReadOnly Property Root As DirectoryInfo
End Interface
```

My registration goes like so:

```
oRoot = New DirectoryInfo(Options.Root)
oParameters = New List(Of Parameter) From {
  New NamedParameter(NameOf(Options.Root), oRoot)
}

oBuilder = New ContainerBuilder
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of UpdateCommand).As(Of IUpdateCommand).WithParameters(oParameters)
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of CleanCommand).As(Of ICleanCommand).WithParameters(oParameters)
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of Downloader).As(Of IDownloader)()
```

...and here's how I'm resolving them:

```
Dim oUpdateCommand As IUpdateCommand
Dim oCleanCommand As ICleanCommand

Using oScope As ILifetimeScope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope
  oUpdateCommand = oScope.Resolve(Of IUpdateCommand)
  oCleanCommand = oScope.Resolve(Of ICleanCommand)
  oDownloader = oScope.Resolve(Of IDownloader)
End Using
```

Here's the error I'm getting when I try to resolve `oDownloader`:

> None of the constructors found on type 'VsLayout.Downloader' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'VsLayout.IBaseCommand Command' of constructor 'Void .ctor(VsLayout.IBaseCommand)'.
>
> See https://autofac.rtfd.io/help/no-constructors-bindable for more info.

The documentation doesn't address this scenario, unfortunately.

I tried altering my registration slightly, specifying `IBaseCommand` instead of `IUpdateCommand`/`ICleanCommand`:

```
oBuilder = New ContainerBuilder
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of UpdateCommand).As(Of IBaseCommand).WithParameters(oParameters)
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of CleanCommand).As(Of IBaseCommand).WithParameters(oParameters)
oBuilder.RegisterType(Of Downloader).As(Of IDownloader)()
```

...but that results in a different error when resolving:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=The requested service 'VsLayout.IUpdateCommand' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
>
> See https://autofac.rtfd.io/help/service-not-registered for more info.

Again, the docs don't cover this specific scenario.

I then tried shifting the resolution a bit:

```
Dim oUpdateCommand As IUpdateCommand
Dim oCleanCommand As ICleanCommand
Dim oDownloader As IDownloader

Using oScope As ILifetimeScope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope
  oUpdateCommand = oScope.Resolve(Of IBaseCommand)
  oCleanCommand = oScope.Resolve(Of IBaseCommand)
  oDownloader = oScope.Resolve(Of IDownloader)
End Using
```

That doesn't work, because an `IBaseCommand` object can't be cast to an `IUpdateCommand`. Sure, I could declare `oUpdateCommand` as an `IBaseCommand`, and that'd run, but `IUpdateCommand` is eventually going to have unique properties on it that I'm going to need.

In the end, the `Downloader` class must take an abstract as its parameter, because both `UpdateCommand` and `CleanCommand` are going to use it.

So are we stuck? How do we use Autofac with inheritance like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this, in a great tip in the comments for [this answer by @nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373371).

The working code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports Autofac
Imports Autofac.Core
Imports CommandLine
Imports CommandLine.Text
Imports Intexx.Linq

Friend Module Program
  Friend Sub Main(Args As String())
    Dim oParameters As List(Of Parameter)
    Dim oHelpText As HelpText
    Dim oResult As ParserResult(Of Options)
    Dim oParser As Parser
    Dim oRoot As DirectoryInfo
    Dim eYear As Years

    oParser = New Parser(Sub(Settings)
                         End Sub)

    oResult = oParser.ParseArguments(Of Options)(Args)

    oResult.
      WithParsed(Sub(Options)
                   If Enums(Of Years).Descriptions.Contains(Options.Year) Then
                     oRoot = New DirectoryInfo(Options.Root)
                     Enums(Of Years).TryGetValue(Options.Year, eYear, SearchBy.Description)

                     oParameters = New List(Of Parameter) From {
                       New NamedParameter(NameOf(Options.Root), oRoot),
                       New NamedParameter(NameOf(Options.Year), eYear),
                       New NamedParameter(NameOf(Options.Edition), Options.Edition)
                     }

                     With New ContainerBuilder
                       .RegisterType(Of UpdateCommand).As(Of IBaseCommand).
                       Named(Of IBaseCommand)(NameOf(IUpdateCommand)).
                       WithParameters(oParameters)

                       .RegisterType(Of CleanCommand).As(Of IBaseCommand).
                       Named(Of IBaseCommand)(NameOf(ICleanCommand)).
                       WithParameters(oParameters)

                       .RegisterType(Of Downloader).As(Of IDownloader)()

                       Run(.Build)
                     End With
                   Else
                     oHelpText = HelpText.AutoBuild(oResult,
                                                    Function(HelpText) HelpText,
                                                    Function(Example) Example,
                                                    maxDisplayWidth:=120)

                     Console.WriteLine(oHelpText)
                     Environment.Exit(-1)
                   End If
                 End Sub).
      WithNotParsed(Sub(Errors)

                    End Sub)
  End Sub



  Friend Sub Run(Container As IContainer)
    Dim oUpdateCommand As IUpdateCommand
    Dim oCleanCommand As ICleanCommand
    Dim oDownloader As IDownloader

    Using oScope As ILifetimeScope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope
      oUpdateCommand = oScope.ResolveNamed(Of IBaseCommand)(NameOf(IUpdateCommand))
      oCleanCommand = oScope.ResolveNamed(Of IBaseCommand)(NameOf(ICleanCommand))
      oDownloader = oScope.Resolve(Of IDownloader)
    End Using
  End Sub
End Module
```

This has been an adventure!